# CORS in ASP.NET Core 2 does not work despite setting it up correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I have setup CORS in my asp.net core 2 project, however it does not work, on every request I am getting a "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" Error.

At the top of configureservices I have added a new policy.

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Default", builder =>
{
    builder
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .WithOrigins("https://www.in2work.co.uk", "https://in2work.co.uk", "http://localhost:4200", "https://in2work.co.uk:80", "https://www.in2work.co.uk:80")
        .Build();
}));
```

And in startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, InitialSeeder seeder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("Default");

    loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/cmsapi_{Date}.txt");

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at (URL) (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). I have tried without the build before and it hasn't changed anything, while it is redundant it seems that it does not effect functionality. Any ideas?

Comment: There seems to be no exceptions. https://codeshare.io/5wAzqJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close any sites that you have served on your machine and check again to see if any of the requests works.

Comment: Thank you. This worked, however after this I had an error message pop up with an exception which helped me to further solve the issue.